# Unicorn periodically fails to restart after deploy - stale PID

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, unicorn, pid, upstart

I've been trying to solve this problem on my own for sometime and have not had any luck. It occurs when I redeploy my rails app about 10% of the time. The other 90% of the time the deploy goes smoothly.

I've tried and tried again, but have not succeeded. So I'm turning to the SO masses for some help.

A little about my stack: I'm using chef to generate my instance on vagrant running on Ubuntu 14.04 and using upstart to oversea unicorn.

The error:

```
srv/www/rails/releases/ef6a792a19f8bb9d36ef4d0ab15ee38ca91a0cd1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:206:in `pid=': Already running on PID:17694 (or pid=/srv/www/rails/shared/pids/unicorn.pid is stale) (ArgumentError)
from /srv/www/rails/releases/ef6a792a19f8bb9d36ef4d0ab15ee38ca91a0cd1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:135:in `start'
from /srv/www/rails/releases/ef6a792a19f8bb9d36ef4d0ab15ee38ca91a0cd1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
from /srv/www/rails/releases/ef6a792a19f8bb9d36ef4d0ab15ee38ca91a0cd1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
from /srv/www/rails/releases/ef6a792a19f8bb9d36ef4d0ab15ee38ca91a0cd1/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

My unicorn upstart script is [here](https://github.com/D1plo1d/unicorn/blob/master/templates/ubuntu/unicorn-upstart.conf.erb). And my unicorn configuration file can be viewed [here](https://github.com/D1plo1d/unicorn/blob/master/templates/default/unicorn.rb.erb).

Please let me know if you need any more information. And above thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

I've been running into this too.  You need to clear out the old PID file in your upstart script, before you try running Unicorn.

```
rm /srv/www/rails/shared/pids/unicorn.pid
```

Alternatively, take a look at https://github.com/tablexi/capistrano3-unicorn for ways to determine server state and start/restart Unicorn appropriately.